# Twitter tweet contact widget

Tags: twitter

Is there a twitter widget to let users on a website tweet at you from a form field on a webpage?

I'm wondering if I could replace a contact form with just a text area field that lets users tweet to my account if users have a twitter account and are logged in.

I don't see any widgets on Twitter website that allow this:
https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview

Apologies if this is not the right forum to post this question.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't present the text field on your site unless you first take the user through [the authentication flow](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth) to get an access token. For a simple "contact me" situation, it's unlikely many users will want to allow your site to tweet on their behalf.

You can use the [Tweet button](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button) to popup the Twitter interface with a pre-populated mention using a URL like this:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=@username
```